# compositing 4 scenes from 4 camera views, remove overlapping areas of final composite

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have tried for a week to get this to work. I am trying to create a setup for a pyramid peppers ghost output. I have 4 scenes linked and using a mask I can get the cameras to composite correctly so that the final composite has the shape of the cameras correct. However, the background of the output overlaps the other images and prevents the output from working correctly. I need the full view to be "cut" into the shape of the alpha mask that I am using so that the output does not leak into the next view for the pyramid. The large X output is just a layout to see where the images land in the setup. If black you do not see the overlaps clearly. it is from a 5th camera view.

[image: output of composite. The lower camera render shows that it outputs the triangle shape needed]

How can I create a node setup or anything else that would force the shape needed onto the 4 views composited?

My node setup for the current layout is below. hopefully it makes sense what I am doing so far. Everything is repeated between the render layer setups so i tried to screenshot 2 so you can see what is happening in each render layer.

[image: compositing screenshot]

Comment: I could get the camera view to show without overlap if I also had transparency on with rgba. However, I was still having issues with that setup. The answer from Leonardo is the better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution would be to first transform the rendered image, and on top of that apply a mask of the size of the final render, that way the alpha channel would not be distorted along with the scaled image.
I send you the [.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oWBMV5OOBsovzNPcNPTZAP6UnJxAMQEW/view?usp=sharing) project that I made with my solution, I hope it helps you.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer. Sometimes I can get so far into something that I cannot see what should be clear. Your perspective was needed.

Comment: Hi @MichaelDot! If the answer worked for you.. it's a nice idea to upvote it as well as tick it, on SE sites

Comment: I do not yet have the ability. just tried. I will remember for the future though.